# Build Your First Network example does not update balance after switching the endorsement policy from OR to AND

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am experimenting with changing the fabric chaincode endorsement policy from OR to AND.  When the endorsement policy is OR, everything works fine and the balances are updated.  After I have switched the endorsement policy to AND and recreate all containers, the balances are not updated anymore.  In the peer0 org1 container, I see the following warnings and errors.  Similar errors are found in peer0 org2 container too.

```
2018-02-15 20:08:11.778 UTC [vscc] Invoke -> WARN 8d4 Endorsement policy failure for transaction txid=2742f25b173374674c6f9796fe11d8ad37bc52fe332ffa420fa04a272b67d927, err: Failed to authenticate policy
2018-02-15 20:08:11.779 UTC [txvalidator] VSCCValidateTxForCC -> ERRO 8de VSCC check failed for transaction txid=2742f25b173374674c6f9796fe11d8ad37bc52fe332ffa420fa04a272b67d927, error VSCC error: policy evaluation failed, err Failed to authenticate policy
2018-02-15 20:08:11.779 UTC [txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 8e2 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = 2742f25b173374674c6f9796fe11d8ad37bc52fe332ffa420fa04a272b67d927 returned error VSCC error: policy evaluation failed, err Failed to authenticate policy
2018-02-15 20:08:11.780 UTC [valimpl] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 8ea Block [4] Transaction index [0] marked as invalid by committer. Reason code [10]
```

The only thing I have changed is the policy part of the peer chaincode instantiate command: -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"

Are there other configurations or commands need to be changed?  Thank You!

cd to the first-network directory and execute the following commands:

```
../../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d
```

Get into the cli container and execute the following commands:

```
docker exec -it cli bash
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
echo $CHANNEL_NAME
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel peer channel join -b mychannel.block
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'  #this shows 100 as expected
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'  #this shows 200 as expected
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'  #this still shows 100 and is not changed.
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","b"]}'  #this still shows 200 and is not changed.
```

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense, because the peer CLI (peer chaincode *, peer channel *, etc. etc.) binary can only collect an endorsement from a single peer.

When you define CORE_PEER_ADDRESS it basically tells the peer CLI, which peer it should contact.

An endorsment policy that has an AND, obviously needs more than 1 peer, so that's why the transactions fail...

Comment: Hi, yacovm, does it mean that this cannot be tested (AND policy) with the peer commands?  If yes, then this has to be tested with Node js or java programs using the fabric client SDK.  Correct?

Comment: Correct... to test it you need to use an SDK.